# get value of columnname from magento grid to controller

Tags: magento, controller, grid, edit

In magento, I have grid having columns id, name, email etc. Column name is of type input. If I edit input box of 'name' and do any mass action then in controller, how can I get value of input text in 'name' column ?

Comment: Even I have had a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880272/magento-creating-ajax-based-editable-grid.

Comment: As i got you want to show values on some mass action .If yes than you first check the last parameter of the action like normally ("edit" or "delete") than in your controller find the action for that name.your question is not fully clear.